# How do you change the output of sudo hwclock?

Tags: pi-3, rtc

Just recieved a new RTC for my Raspberry Pi.

When I use the `sudo hwclock` command the output looks like the following:

2018-01-08 13:06:5.441956+0100

On my other Raspberry Pi’s the output looks like:

mon 08 jan 2018 13:06:05 CET -0.082820 seconds

So what I want to know is how do I change the output of `sudo hwclock`?